MSCOMM32 in VBA (Access Database)
Let say, my application in VBA (Access) crashes with the serial port open
MyForm!MSComm1.PortOpen = true
Restarting the program shows "MyForm!MSComm1.PortOpen = False", so I do a "MyForm!MSComm1.PortOpen = TRUE" and I get the error that the port is already open, even though it reports as not open.
If I exit the Access database, reload it, it works fine again.  It is not like another program has control of the port, but that is what it looks like.
It looks like part of the application code may still be running in memory, even though I can't see it.
If I properly close the port before doing anything (i.e., taking the form to design mode) it is okay.  If the port is connected and I go to design mode, I can never use the port again unless I exist access and re-load the database.
